# Set certain size and content to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing an Rails 3.2.14 app and in this app I am creating
an array with exactly 31 zeros in it:

```
<% @total = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] %>
```

I know there must be a better way to do this right?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Array.new` is probably the cleanest way to do this:

```
Array.new(31, 0)
```

The first argument is the size, the second is the default value.

Some other alternatives:

```
[0] * 31
31.times.collect{0}
31.times.inject([]){|array, count| array << 0}
```

These methods are trivial if you're filling with zeros, but if you are calculating values then they can be quite powerful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-c-new) or [Array#fill](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-fill).

Example:

```
Array.new(31, 0)
```

or

```
[].fill(0, 0..30)
```

both yields the same result.